# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

This [question has more than 2k views](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67292/latex-error-log-file-not-found) in just over 15 months. I too am experiencing the `File not Found` message and this question describes my problem. I notice that the person who asked this question had a rating of 6, which to me means he was probably new to Texmaker. I have just installed TexMaker on Windows7 and am getting the same error message. I don't think it is too localized and I don't think 2k+ views in 15 months is a small audience. Instead, this is an error message a new user gets.

Since that question is closed. Where on StackExchange should I ask the question: " `I get File not Found` error message when using Texmaker?"

Comment: Please have a look at [Common mistakes/errors Using TeXmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717) if it helps. Best idea would be to Follow the Linked and Related Q's to your closed Q. If you found any answer in any Related Q's may be the community would make the closed Q a Duplicate for future visitors. I just made a related Q's comment to have it listed in the `Linked Q's`.

Comment: Possibly Related [Reopen or Migrate LyX & MiKTeX installation question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3956/15717)

Comment: I believe the question was closed because there was no way to answer it, since the user didn't reply to the comments asking for clarification. Feel free to post a new question, but make sure to include the details necessary for reproducing the problem.